# How to make external hard drive (or folder on it) available to others on the same network

Tags: wireless-networking, hard-drive

I want to make my external drive (or at least a folder on it) available to others in my dorm to upload and download files from.  I've been looking around and I haven't seen any simple solutions for this.  I was wondering if it is possible to host a local server on my computer that can be accessed by my ip and upload and download from there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the drive or folder you want to share, click on sharing settings and share it with either everyone or selected device on the network. 
I am assuming you all are connected to same WiFi network and your PCs can talk to each other.

Comment: I already tried this and I could not find it from my mac or from my friends computer.  I was hoping to just make it run a simple server so I could just give out my local ip and have people connect that way.

Comment: You can give teamviewer a try. Using it you could eaven acces files remotely even when connected to differebt netwoks.